# php: file_get_contents() works for every external website, but doesn't work for page on same host

Tags: php, nginx, file-get-contents

Server has nginx and php on it.

When i am trying to `echo file_get_contents();` with any website as input - everything works fine

when i am trying to `echo file_get_contents();` with url of page which is on the same server - timeout shows up.

I tried using cURL as well. It won't work, drops timeouts also.

Comment: if its the same server why are you not using the file path?

Comment: can you show how exactly you use `file_get_contents()` on your page which is on the same server?

Comment: @smith well, there is front-end and back-end on that server, the back-end makes some data aggregations and hosts all the data in DB. Front end (let say api.php file) gives ability to request that data from DB. So as example:  mywebfrontend.com/api.php?metric=users returns users list. So it must be call to dynamic/executable .php file , i can't file_get_content simple .php as source.

Comment: @wayneOS `echo file_get_contents('https://node.myserver.com/api.php');` , even when i created simple index.php file in the root of my web , `echo file_get_contents('https://node.setupad.com/index.php');` shows nothing, just `504 Gateway Time-out`

Comment: Are you able to show the code? Also, is the timeout you are experiencing a connection timeout (TCP SYN) or are you just getting an unexpected response?

Comment: check the apache access logs they should show the attempt to access the file.

Comment: @Nathan check comment above. I get `504 Gateway Time-out
nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: @smith `2018/04/05 23:26:03 [error] 15729#15729: *27015 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.*.*.*, server: node.myhost.com, request: "GET /node/file_get_content_test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/php-nginx/15228774427214.sock/socket", host: "node.myhost.com"`

Comment: "Gateway Time-out" suggests that the local web server may be a proxy. It could be that it does not like something about the request headers created by the PHP file_get_contents() compared to the ones generated via cURL. Would be good if the request could be captured (both using cURL and the PHP function or request into netcat). Also read through the Nginx config file if you have access to it.

Comment: well that gives you some errors to google at least, on the other side curl sets a load of headers file_get_contents does not, i always use curl for external resources dues to all greater tool set, may not be the answer you want but if it works, and the other method does not ..

Comment: Ouch guys, it seems that curl also doesn't! I was accidentally curling from my laptop terminal. When curling through php or ssh while connected to  that server - it also timeouts.

Comment: check your `/etc/hosts` or `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file to see if there's a line for the domain of the backend

Comment: Could the Nginx configuration be denying proxied connections originating from localhost? Are you able to post the Nginx server configuration?

Comment: @Cemal at server `/etc/hosts` has only `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: How about iptables or a similar firewall? It may have a setting where only request from a few ips to server are accepted. This kind of practice is very common for servers behind a proxy like cloudflare

Comment: @Cemal yep! the hosting providers admins stepped in and it seemed that there were no hostname record mapped with local IP in /etc/hosts. Thanks your comments were closest ones! If you want you can answer this topic with normal answer and i will mark it as solution. Thanks!

Comment: it's ok, glad I could be of help. I didn't solve it, you and the tech guys did. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet limitation access on your network! I have my own solved!